# segmenting bs4.element.Tag

Tags: beautifulsoup, nlp, html-parsing, text-segmentation

Is it possible to segment a `bs4.element.Tag` into several `bs4.element.Tag`?

You can think of an application as the following:

1- The original `bs4.element.Tag` contains a paragraph.

2- We want to segment the paragraph in the original `bs4.element.Tag` into sentences and get a `bs4.element.Tag` corresponding to each sentence.

**Example:**

`paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')` gives all the paragraphs in an HTML file.

Suppose a paragraph (which is also a `bs4.element.Tag` instance) is the following:

```
<p><i><a href="/wiki/Le_Bassin_Aux_Nymph%C3%A9as" title="Le Bassin Aux Nymphéas">Le Bassin Aux Nymphéas</a></i>, 1919. Monet's late series of water lily paintings are among his best-known works.
```

I would like to turn this `bs4.element.Tag` instance (which is also a paragraph) into 2 `bs4.element.Tag` instances as the following (one for each sentence):

First `bs4.element.Tag` should correspond to the first sentence:

```
<i><a href="/wiki/Le_Bassin_Aux_Nymph%C3%A9as" title="Le Bassin Aux Nymphéas">Le Bassin Aux Nymphéas</a></i>, 1919.
```

Second `bs4.element.Tag` should correspond to the second sentence:

```
Monet's late series of water lily paintings are among his best-known works.
```

Comment: Can you share some HTML including the desired output?

Comment: @MendelG I just edited the question and added an example.

Comment: The text _"1919."_ is part of the _first_ paragraph?

Comment: @MendelG The text "1919." is part of the first sentence.

Comment: Is it okay if the the type of the two paragraphs are `str` instead of `bs4.element.Tag`?

Comment: @MendelG That is the main issue. `str` would be simple because we can use `get_text()`. However, since I am doing further processing, I still need `bs4.element.Tag`.